Pixel text in Godot
I'm making a pixel art game, and I'm using the Pixel Perfect feature for that. Maybe because of this feature, my text is pixelated. Can you please tell me how to solve this problem? The sprites are fine, but the text is not readable. Screenshot of the problem

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Back when Godot didn't have a good pixel perfect solution, people used to have a viewport fot the world (with some extra trickery to make it pixel perfect), and then UI outside, so it could be rendered normally.
See How to make a silky smooth camera for pixelart games in Godot (3.x).
Of course, in Godot 4, it is a bit different. The gist of it is that you can use a SubViewport (Viewport in Godot 3) inside a ViewportContainer, or a SubViewport followed by a sibling TextureRect that takes a ViewportTexture from the SubViewport if you need more control over how it is displayed. And you can also apply shaders on it for extra effect, but you do not need that for your use case. The simplest setup should do.
